# Rewrite Java code to Python(function) but it does not work

Tags: python, java

I want to rewrite a Java function in Python but it doesn't really work the way I want it to. This is how the Java code looks like:

```
public String matchText(String[] splitText, String[] clozeText, int emptySpaces){
    String result="";
    for(int i=0;i<splitText.length;i++){
        if (splitText[i].equals(clozeText[0])){
            if(splitText[i+emptySpaces].equals(clozeText[emptySpaces+1])){
                for (int x=i;i<=i+emptySpaces;x++){
                    result += splitText[x];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

And this is my attempt:

```py
def matchText(splitText, clozeText, emptySpaces):
    result = ""
    for i in range(len(splitText)):
        if splitText[i] == clozeText[0]:
            if splitText[i + emptySpaces] == clozeText[emptySpaces + 1]:
                for x in emptySpaces:
                    result += splitText[x]
    return result
```

Comment: You should include how you want it to work and how it works instead.

Comment: When I run the function in Java it works, but not in Python. I just want to know if I have the syntax etc. right here.

Comment: Please describe the inputs, the expected results for the inputs and the actual results (output or errors) of your Python code. Right now, you're trying to use us as human debuggers, while debugging is your responsibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner for loop should be

```
for x in range(i, i + emptySpaces + 1):
    result += splitText[x]
```

This is the correct implementation:

```
from typing import List

def matchText(splitText: List[str], clozeText: List[str], emptySpaces: int) -> str:
    result = ""
    for i in range(len(splitText)):
        if splitText[i] == clozeText[0]:
            if splitText[i + emptySpaces] == clozeText[emptySpaces + 1]:
                for x in range(i, i + emptySpaces + 1):
                    result += splitText[x]
    return result
```

You can't do `for x in emptySpaces` because `emptySpaces` is an integer! You can't iterate integers. That's why your approach is not working in Python.

Note that I also added types to arguments and returned result (this is optional, but it helps you understand how the function works).